# JavaScript autosave text to file on client-side

Tags: javascript, autosave

I am using a code editor and a file view, I want whatever the user type in the code editor auto saves in the file. I have a function to download the file with the current text inside like this:

```js
function saveFile() {
    var text = editor.doc.getValue();
    var text = text.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");
    var blob = new Blob([text], {type: "text/x-python;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, selectedFileName.name);
}
```

using a FileSaver.js, link: http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js.

I store the files in a file array and display them as unordered list.

Currently I am replacing the whole file like this:

```js
fileList[0] = new File(["content"], "filename");
```

Can I update the text of a file in the fileList directly, without the need of creating a new file and replacing it?

Comment: your requirement is not much clear. Can you explain little bit more

Comment: I have a filelist, and if I want to change the text of a file I have to create a new file and replace the current file. Can I change the text of the current file without the need of replacing the whole file? @Yushan

Comment: The answer is no. You will always have to open a file, make changes and save it, hence 'creating new file' by replacing old.

Comment: You mean the changes should be reflected on the user's disk or only in the FileList object (i.e only in memory) or only in the File object you had (i.e edit the underlying value in memory that the File object points to)? The first two are doable (in some browsers), the latter is impossible: Blob and File objects are immutable. But it's unclear why you'd want to do that anyway. Getting rid of the unused File objects is just okay. Also, if you're going to modify these text's content a lot, why use a File to store it? Store strings instead, and only build the Blob at export.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local sotage for store data at client side.
// Store

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
```

// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");

Comment: It didnt work for me. Right now what is working is replacing the whole file like this:
"fileList[0] = new File[..blah blah]"
Can I change the text of fileList[0] without the need of replacing the file?